# Apk download count Google Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play

I have small doubt on APK download counts. My app is already there on play store and it's download counts are around 500 - 1000, And now i'm gona upload the same apk from different credentials What will happen my counts will start from the same count or start from 0.
Having small doubts, any kind of help will be good for me thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll lose all your download counts. It will start from 0..

Comment: @HelloWorld thank you HelloWorld

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can't upload same app from 2 different credentials. Play Store won't allow you to. The package name needs to differ.

Comment: if i'll unpulished the app and then uploading from different login will my downloads remains the same or will start from 0.

Comment: No. Even if you un-publish, Google Play Store won't let you upload the app with same package name. You will have to upload the app as new app with different package name and in that case the count will start from 0.

What you can do however is request Google to transfer the app from one account to other. Here's the link https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247?hl=en on how to do it.